# Как в Typescript получить ошибку из запроса в виде объекта?

Tags: javascript, json, веб-программирование, typescript, type-error

Необходимо сделать GET-запрос на сервер, который вернёт массив объектов `Message[]`. При некорректном запросе сервер возвращает ошибку JSON с полями `code: int, message: string, timestamp: time.Date`. Можно сделать стандартный запрос:

```
async function getMessages(): Promise<Message[]> {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(...)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(...)
    }

    return await response.json() as Message[]
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

В таком случае ошибка просто выведется в консоль. Но хотелось бы в основном коде ее получить как объект `ResponseError` и дальше с ней работать. Подскажите, как правильно написать пример такой функции и правильно обработать ее результаты